# Renaming files programmatically, decrementing

Tags: c#, file, rename

I have a folder with a certain number of text files named `1.txt, 2.txt 3.txt` etc.

My goal is that when one of them is deleted, to rename any of the files greater than the file deleted down one.

Ex. if 1.txt is deleted, 2 should be renamed to 1, and 3 renamed to 2, so on and so forth.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
 private void deletequestionbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fileDel = testfolderdialog.SelectedPath.ToString() + @"\" + questionCountint.ToString() + ".txt";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(testfolderdialog.SelectedPath.ToString() + @"\");

        File.Delete(fileDel);
        questionCountint++;

        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt"))
        {
            string fn = file.Name;
            string use = fn.Replace(".txt", "");
            int count = int.Parse(use);

            if (count > questionCountint)
            {              
                File.Move(fileDel, testfolderdialog.SelectedPath.ToString() + @"\" + questionCountint--.ToString() + ".txt");
            }          
        }             
    }
```

The issue is occuring on the `File.Move` line, it's saying it cannot locate the file in `fileDel`, though I am incrementing `questionCountint` after deleting `fileDel`

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Is there a more effective way to write the `foreach` statement? I only want to rename the files greater than the file deleted.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: XY problem, "How can I roll my own log roller to rotate my logs"

Comment: PS. The answer is Regex. https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: Have you looked at what the value of` `questionCountint` is that us used to construct the destination file name when you try to  do the move? I think you will find that it is not the value you expect.

Comment: @Alex I just checked. After deleting 2.txt, questionCountint becomes 3. But in the File.Move line, it tells me it can't find 2.txt...Not sure why it's looking for it as questionCountint is 3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to rename `fileDel`, which is the file that you have deleted. You should rename `file` instead.

However, you will quickly run into the next problem. If you don't get the files in the exact order that you expect, you will try to rename a file to a name that already exists.

If the `GetFiles` method returns the files in the order `"3.txt", "2.txt"`, you will first try to rename `"3.txt"` to `"2.txt"`, but `"2.txt"` already exists.

You should first loop through the files and gather all files that should be renamed. Then you should sort the files on the number so that you can rename them in the correct order.

As the format of the file names is so simple to recreate from the number, you can just get the numbers in a list:

```
List<int> files = new List<int>();
foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt")) {
  string fn = file.Name;
  string use = fn.Replace(".txt", "");
  int count = int.Parse(use);
  if (count > questionCountint) {
    files.Add(count);
  }
}
string path = testfolderdialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
foreach (int count in files.Ordery(n => n)) {
  File.Move(String.Concat(path, count.ToString() + ".txt"), String.Concat(path, (count - 1).ToString() + ".txt");
}
```